# Aerospike EE Startup Error - feature invalid value 2 for feature feature-key-version

Tags: aerospike

Aerospike Version: Aerospike Enterprise Edition build 4.9.0.37 os el7

**Feature File**

```
# generated 2023-04-25 19:57:16

feature-key-version              2

serial-number                    <ommited>

account-name                     Aerospike_TRIAL_8node

account-ID                       Aerospike_20230418

valid-until-date                 2023-07-31

asdb-change-notification         true
asdb-cluster-nodes-limit         8
asdb-compression                 true
asdb-encryption-at-rest          true
asdb-flash-index                 true
asdb-ldap                        true
asdb-pmem                        true
asdb-rack-aware                  true
asdb-strong-consistency          true
asdb-vault                       true
asdb-xdr                         true
elasticsearch-connector          true
mesg-jms-connector               true
mesg-kafka-connector             true
presto-connector                 true
pulsar-connector                 true
raf-realtime-analysis-framework  true
spark-connector                  true

----- SIGNATURE ------------------------------------------------
<ommited>
----- END OF SIGNATURE -----------------------------------------
```

**aerospike.conf**

```
# Aerospike database configuration file for use with systemd.

service {
    paxos-single-replica-limit 1 # Number of nodes where the replica count is automatically reduced to 1.
    proto-fd-max 15000
    feature-key-file /etc/aerospike/features.conf
}

logging {
    #console {
    #   context any info
    #}
    # Log file must be an absolute path.
        file /var/log/aerospike/aerospike.log {
                context any info
        }
}

network {
    service {
        address any
        port 3000
    }

    heartbeat {
        mode mesh
        address 0.0.0.0
        port 3002 # Heartbeat port for this node.

        #mode multicast
        #multicast-group 239.1.99.222
        #port 9918

        mesh-seed-address-port centos-7-0  3002
        mesh-seed-address-port centos-7-1  3002
        mesh-seed-address-port centos-7-2  3002

        # To use unicast-mesh heartbeats, remove the 3 lines above, and see
        # aerospike_mesh.conf for alternative.

        interval 150
        timeout 10
    }

    fabric {
        port 3001
    }

    info {
        port 3003
    }
}

namespace demo {
    replication-factor 2
    memory-size 1G

    storage-engine memory

    # To use file storage backing, comment out the line above and use the
    # following lines instead.
    storage-engine device {
        device /dev/sdb1
        write-block-size 128K
    }
}
```

**Error Encountered**

```
Jun 04 2023 23:40:26 GMT: CRITICAL (config): (features_ee.c:391) invalid value 2 for feature feature-key-version in /etc/aerospike/features.conf, line 3
Jun 04 2023 23:40:26 GMT: WARNING (as): (signal.c:166) SIGINT received, shutting down Aerospike Enterprise Edition build 4.9.0.37 os el7
Jun 04 2023 23:40:26 GMT: WARNING (as): (signal.c:169) startup was not complete, exiting immediately
```

Upon startup.

Answer (score 0):

A version 2 feature key would only work with versions 5.4 and above. For 4.9, you would need a version 1 feature key.

See release [5.4](https://enterprise.aerospike.com/enterprise/download/server/notes.html#5.4.0.1) and this specific line item:

[AER-6355] - (DEPLOYMENT) Added support for feature-key-version 2.